# Custom loss function IoU is not differentiable. Can you create a differentiable IoU loss function for ML?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, loss-function

I'm currently developing the peak detection algorithm using CNN to determine the ideal convolution kernel which is representable as the ideal mother wavelet function that will maximize the peak detection accuracy.

I've tried to create my own IoU loss function for the CNN training model, but I failed.
My own loss function is described as below.

```
'''
1D intersection over union loss function class
'''
class IoU(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, thresh: float = 0.5):
    super().__init__()
    self.thresh = thresh

  def forward(self, inputs: torch.Tensor, targets:torch.Tensor, weights: Optional[torch.Tensor] = None, smooth: float = 0.0) -> Tensor:

    inputs = torch.where(inputs < self.thresh, 0, 1)
    batch_size = targets.shape[0]

    intersect = torch.logical_and(inputs, targets)
    intersect = intersect.view(batch_size, -1).sum(-1)

    union = torch.logical_and(inputs, targets)
    union = union.view(batch_size, -1).sum(-1)

    IoU = (intersect + smooth) / (union + smooth)
    IoU = IoU.mean()

    return IoU
```

and I tried to test whether this works or not by these simple model like below.

```
x = torch.tensor(0, 1001, 256) # e.g. [0, 200, 30, 1000, ...]
true = torch.tensor(0, 2, 256) # e.g. [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, ...]

model = nn.Linear(256, 256)
criterion = IoU()

output = model(x)
loss = criterion(output, true)
loss.backward() # I'm stuck on here, cause my loss func IoU is not differentiable

print(f"loss ={loss}")
print(f"model weight: {model.weight.grad}")
print(f"model params: [x.grad for x in {model.parameters()]")
```

And the output on the terminal is `RuntimeError: element 0 of variables does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn`

This project is the time ever for me to use PyTorch, so I didn't know what it meant at the first glance, but after my quick research, I figured out why this loss function fails (I'm not sure this is correct though)

### my loss function IoU is not differentiable.

and

#### This is where the chain rule of this loss function break.

```
IoU = torch.nan_to_num(IoU)
IoU = IoU.mean()
```

Soon after I noticed this, I took a deeper look at the GitHub or stack overflow to find any other differentiable IoU loss function, but I'm still not sure **how to create a differentiable IoU loss function** (especially for 1D data).

Thank you

Comment: A bit more info on the formulation of your task would be helpful. What is input / target? Is input the value of the wavelet function at discrete times, or a parameterization of the wavelet? By IOU do you mean the difference between the two waveforms, integrated over time/samples? If so, I believe RMSE of difference between the two functions is equivalent for the 1-dimensioanl case. But the use of the term IOU might be a bit misleading. Precisely, 1D iou is, given two line segments, compare the length of the intersection of these 1D line segments to the overall length of the line segments

Comment: And getting to your issue, nan to num is not a differentiable function so autograd is not implemented for it. It is essentially a "floor" function on the inputs, which of course would also not be differentiable.

Comment: Oh also, your first problem is that torch.tensor does not do what you expect it to it seems. If you want random values use `torch.rand()`

Comment: @DerekG
Thank your for your series of advice, it helps a lot!
I was about to reply with more detailed information on this problem but I could fix my loss function according to [Custom loss function IoU is not differentiable. Can you create a differentiable IoU loss function for ML - discuss.pytorch.org](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/custom-loss-function-iou-is-not-differentiable-can-you-create-a-differentiable-iou-loss-function-for-ml/148899/3)

Comment: but I faced another problem, which is,
## The parameters of the model with custom loss function doesn’t upgraded thorough its learning over epochs

This must be another topic, so I posted new topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71855440/the-parameters-of-the-model-with-custom-loss-function-doesn-t-upgraded-thorough)

Thank you!
pasiveradio